Whats the difference between gaslighting and lying?
They seem to be the same thing, to gaslight someone and to lie to someone sounds like an identical action.
I've looked in a dictionary.
but I still can't envision a cenario in which if I switch one word for the other, the meaning of a sentence would change.
They seem to be synonyms with extra steps.

Look in a dictionary.

@Lambie I've looked, but I still can't envision a cenario in which if I switch one word for the other the meaning would change

gaslighting is saying things to make me angry or upset and often by going on and on. gaslighting is not necessarily lying. The answer you got below is right.

@Lambie Can you make a sentence with the word 'gaslighting' or a variation of it. So if you switch the word with the word 'lying' the meaning of the sentence would change.

Gaslighting always involves some lying, but there are many, many forms of lying without any gaslighting. Witnesses lie to investigators, but it is difficult to envisage the circumstances in which it would be apt to say that a witness was was gaslighting the investigators.

Sorry can't play that game. :) [scenario, by the way]


Gaslighting is a form of psychological abuse, targetted at someone's psyche to alter the way they think, over time.
Lying is simply telling a false statement to deceive someone.

Gaslighting is trying to make the target question their understanding, recollection, or their world-view.

Example Lie: "You have too-much coffee in the morning"
Example Gaslighting: "you'd have spotted the difference between GL and lie, if you had less coffee in the morning"
The difference is the lie is a statement that is incompatible with the true events.   The Gaslight example is trying to make you believe the coffee is affecting your observational ability, and implies you should drink less coffee to be better.  This is the alteration which separates a lie from gaslighting.

While the first half of the answer is on the right track, the examples in the second half are less than illuminating. It is impossible to fully understand all the nuances of gaslight, in this sense, if one is not familiar with one of the two films (or the theatre play) of that name, on which this use of the word is based.

@jsw29 there are relevant films and plays ?     That would be an answer, if the question hadn't been closed.

All gaslighting involves lying, but not all lying  involves gaslighting. Lying is usually done to benefit the liar; Gaslighting is usually done to disadvantage the listener.

@Greybeard good venn diagram, again,a great point that would make an excellent answer.
